# Cannot find compareTo when receiving comparable Object[]

Tags: java, compareto

The problem is the method is not sure a and b are comparable so the compiler throws a cannot find symbol for compareTo.

```
public class Merge {
    public ArrayList<Object> sorted(Object[] a, Object[] b) {

        int i, j, k;
        i = j = k = 0;
        ArrayList<Object> c = new ArrayList<>();
        while (i < a.length || j < b.length) {
            if (i == a.length) {
                for (j = j; j < b.length; j++) {
                    c.add(k, b[j]);
                    k++;
                }
                break;
            }
            else if (j == b.length) {
                for (i = i; i < a.length; i++) {
                    c.add(k, a[i]);
                    k++;
                }
                break;
            }
            else {
                if ( a[i].equals(b[j]) || a[i].compareTo(b[j]) < 0 ) {
                    c.add(k, a[i]);
                    i++;
                    k++;
                }
                else {
                    c.add(k, b[j]);
                    j++;
                    k++;
                }
            }
        }
        return c;
    }
}
```

The code works when used with Integer. I want to be able to use for example, `sorted(a, b)` being `a = Person[]` and `b = Person[]`. Of course with methods compareTo and equals inside Person.

Should I implement and extend comparable with an ObjectType inside this class and override compareTo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you change the signature to

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> List<T> sorted(T[] a, T[] b)
```

and you will be able to compare `a[i].compareTo(b[i])` and a return a list of hte appropriate type.

Comment: Hey, thanks for helping! Can I use ArrayList<T> instead in the signature? Can you explain a bit why you suggest to use that signature or what topics should I research?

Answer (score 2):

To invoke `compareTo()` on an object, a class must implement `Comparable` interface and override `compareTo()` method. As `Object` class does not implement `Comparable`, the above code will always give you compilation error.

If you want to pass Person object only then you need to change the signature to accept `Person[]` array. If not then, you need to override toString() method (with a meaningful implementation) and change `a[i].compareTo(b[j])` to `a[i].toString().compareTo(b[j].toString())`.