# How to implement a List Class that only accepts Comparable Objects

Tags: java, class, generics, interface, comparable

I am making an implementation of a generic ArrayList class that will follow the given elements natural ordering. I assume there is some way to do this, similar to how TreeSet follows the given elements' natural ordering.

When I use the .compareTo method call on the objects stored within, there is an error that says "Cannot resolve method 'compareTo' in 'E'". How do I tell the compiler that the Object E should only be classes that do implement the comparable interface?

Right now, the relevant code looks like this:

```
public class SortedList<E> {
    ...
    public int indexOf(E value) {
        ...
        else if (value.compareTo(this.get(minIndex)) > 1)...
    }
}
```

This post was close to helping:
[Cannot find compareTo when receiving comparable Object[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35760381/cannot-find-compareto-when-receiving-comparable-object)
but its for one specific static method, while I need the objects for the whole class to be Comparable, and the same addition does not seem to work for the class header.

Is there something I can add to the class header that performs a similar function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify it like this.  This `bounded` type allows both `E` and `subtypes of E` to be compared.

```
public class SortedList<E extends Comparable<? super E>> {
   
    public int indexOf(E value) {
        ...
        else if (value.compareTo(this.get(minIndex)) > 1)...
    }
}
```

Comment: I really thought I tried that haha, but it works like a charm. Thanks! I'll mark as accepted when I can.

Answer (score 3):

You have to mandate that your type parameter is comparable to itself (so it has natural ordering).  You can do this by [bounding the parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html).

```
public class SortedList<E extends Comparable<E>> {
```

Answer (score 1):

The multiple inheritance in Java is very rudimentary but something does exist: a class can implement multiple interfaces. Hence a collection can be declared the way

```
ArrayList<Comparable<?>> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

and then you can only add various classes that implement Comparable to it without bothering with the type hierarchy.

However while implementing Comparable this way does mean there is a method `int compareTo(Object other)`, the internal implementation of this method most often includes type cast and would not accept arbitrary input.

Modern Java suggest using `Comparable<ToSomething>` instead, restricting your Comparables to the narrower category. This `ToSomething` also does not need to be the name of your class, can be another marker interface.